# Printing a triangle in Java

Tags: java

I'm practicing basic coding exercises and trying to print the following triangle in Java:

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

The following code gives me the results but I feel like there must be a much more elegant solution

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone provide some insight into how to make this work in a better way?

Ok, here's some more code that produces the correct result that uses just the two for loops, but it looks even uglier:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2) {
        if (i <= 5) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
        else if(i > 5 && i < 8){
            for(int j = i/2; j > 0; j--){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else{
            for(int j = 1; j > 0; j--){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are skipping each 2nd iteration of the loop because you want to increase two steps at once. You can do this by changing the "i++" in your loop to "i += 2" and "i--" to "i -= 2", that will have the same effect and allows you to remove the if inside both loops.

Another improvement would be using a single outer loop and figuring out whether the inner loop should be increasing or decreasing the amount of asterisks. Maybe you can come up with an equation that gives you the amount of asterisks based on the value of i? (I didn't want to solve it completely so you have some exercise left, just comment if you want a full solution)

Updated with a solution that might be considered elegant as you can change the height of the triangle and there is no repetition:

```
int height = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * height; i += 2) {
    int numAsterisks;
    if (i <= height) {
        numAsterisks = i;
    } else {
        numAsterisks = 2 * height - i;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numAsterisks; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the i+=2 and i-=2 makes a lot more sense. I'm still a bit stuck on just keeping it down to two loops though. Would the equation involve an if statement in the inner j loop based on the value of i?

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep it readable. Elegance doesn't imply doing everything in a single line, but repetition should be avoided. That's why I suggested merging both loops into one, but using an if inside is fine.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the question with my alternative code. . .but it looks pretty ugly. I hope there's a much better way than that.

Comment: Updated my answer by cleaning up the code in your edited post

Comment: It looks like declaring the number of asterisks in a separate variable was key. This makes so much more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
public void printTriangle(int size) {
    int half = size / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int stars = 1 + 2 * (i <= half ? i : size - 1 - i);
        char[] a = new char[stars];
        Arrays.fill(a, '*');
        System.out.println(new String(a));
    }
}
```

Or just a bit more optimized:

```
public void printTriangle(int size) {
    int half = size / 2;
    char[] a = new char[size];
    Arrays.fill(a, '*');
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int stars = 1 + 2 * (i <= half ? i : size - 1 - i);
        System.out.println(new String(a, 0, stars));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your use of Arrays.fill()! What's the output look like?

Comment: The output with 5 as parameter is the expected result. I wouldn't post any solution that doesn't meet that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        print("*");
    }
    print("\n");
}
```

This can be another solution to print a regular right triangle...

Comment: This doesn't print a triangle in the desired shape, the first loop of the poster basically does what your code does already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way of looking at the problem.  By using an integer array, I can solve lots of shape drawing problems by changing the values in the array.

When solving more difficult problems, you would use model classes instead of simple integers.  The idea, however, is the same.

Here's the output.

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

And here's the code:

```
public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] heights = {1, 3, 5, 3, 1};

        for (int i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < heights[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about...

```
int width = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= width; i+=2){
    System.out.println(String.format("%"+i+"s", "").replaceAll(" ", "*"));
}
for (int i = width-2; i > 0; i-=2){
    System.out.println(String.format("%"+i+"s", "").replaceAll(" ", "*"));
}
```

Or, even better yet...

```
int width = 7;
double half = width / 2
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    System.out.println(String.format("%"+((i < half ? i : (width-i-1))*2+1)+"s", "").replaceAll(" ", "*"));
}
```

Gives

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

Comment: Keeping it as short as possible doesn't make it _elegant_. Especially the 2nd version will not be readable a few instances after you've written it, that's not considered an _elegant_ solution.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it's most likely the best way but I was trying to do it without API methods and just two for loops if possible.

Comment: @fpw, Elegant is relative and open to interpretation. I guess it comes down to how you define elegant (> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/how-do-you-define-elegant-code) code. I'd consider this more elegant, than the original question example, but definitely not the MOST elegant solution. I much prefer @ ogregoire's Arrays.fill to generate the stars! (Where's your code solution @fpw?)

Comment: It seems to really depend on interpretation. I consider ogregoire's version even less elegant because it introduces arrays to something that doesn't remotely require them. But since it depends on interpretation, I'll remove my downvote.